# What is the alternative to NtQuerySystemInformation for SystemHandleInformation?

Tags: c, windows, internals

NtQuerySystemInformation is deprecated by Microsoft, and they give [alternatives on the documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntquerysysteminformation) for accomplishing the same tasks.

However, there's no alternative for the `SystemHandleInformation` query. What's the new recommended way for querying open file handles per process?

Comment: at first begin from xp need query `SystemExtendedHandleInformation` instead `SystemHandleInformation`. how i know no any alternative, if you want got this information

Comment: In Windows 8.1+ we can call [`PssCaptureSnapshot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processsnapshot/nf-processsnapshot-psscapturesnapshot) to capture the list of handles in a process, and walk it via `PssWalkSnapshot`. For file objects we get the "File" type name and basic info (e.g. `GrantedAccess`), but we have to duplicate the handle to our process in order to obtain the filename (e.g. via `GetFinalPathNameByHandleW`).